# userInteractionEnabled = NO and stil receive gesture

Tags: objective-c, gestures, collectionview

In my storyboard I have a collectionView with custom UICollectionViewCell class containing a custom UIView. The collectionView has a tap gesture, my goal is to enable/disable the tap if specific rule applies i tried assigning NO to userInteractionEnabled property of the specific cell and the view in it but the gesture stil invokes.

There is a bypass: in the tap gesture action write an if statement to check if the rule applies if not do nothing --> this solution works but its a bypass with poor performance,

what is the right way to do this?